# Dual-Boot проблема

Tags: windows, ubuntu, grub

Была установлена Виндовс 10, установил Ubuntu 18.04 второй системой
Загрузился, установил, но при перезагрузке не было Grub (линукс грузился без отображения Граба). Это я решил. Но теперь при выборе виндовс 10 Grub отображает "Invalid EFI path". Подскажите, что делать мне в такой ситуации?

Comment: https://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=229243.0, https://askubuntu.com/questions/216215/invalid-efi-file-path, http://mintlinux.ru/forum/thread7713.html пробовал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша запись GRUB для Windows подходит для загрузки в режиме BIOS, но не для загрузки в режиме EFI. Это ошибка GRUB. Вы можете:

```
menuentry "Windows 7" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod chain
    set root='(hd0,gpt5)'
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

Я не гарантирую, что это сработает, но может. Если это так, добавьте эту запись в /etc/grub.d/40_custom , чтобы она была создана снова, когда Ubuntu обновляет конфигурацию GRUB.

Другим вариантом является использование другого менеджера загрузки в дополнение к или вместо GRUB. rEFInd, , например, будет автоматически определять как Windows, так и GRUB; и если вы используете ядра версии 3.3.0 или более поздней версии (поставляемые с Ubuntu 12.10, но не с Ubuntu 12.04), вы можете напрямую загружать Linux с rEFInd, полностью обходя GRUB. gummiboot - это еще один вариант с похожими возможностями загрузки, но он требует более ручного обслуживания, если вы хотите напрямую загрузить Linux с gummiboot.